# I need to highlight a cell after a IF statement on excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with my code. I want after the second If statement is run I would want the row that has a "conflict" to be highlighted. I have been playing with the code but I get "object required error" here is my code "This is the IF statement `

```
If (StartTime > RowStartTime) And (StartTime < RowEndTime) Or _
   (RowStartTime > StartTime) And (RowStartTime < EndTime) Then
        msgbox "Conflict"
        ActiveCell.Select
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 8`
```

Sub:

```
Public Sub LoopRows(Appserver As String, StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date)

      Dim x As Integer
      Dim NumROws As Integer
      NumROws = Range("Sheet3!C5").End(xlDown).Row - Range("Sheet3!C5").Row
      Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
      Range("Sheet3!C5").Select
      msgbox Appserver
      msgbox StartTime
      msgbox EndTime
      For x = 1 To NumROws
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        If (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Appserver) Then
             Dim RowStartTime As Date
             Dim RowEndTime As Date
            msgbox ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            RowStartTime = Val(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value)
            RowEndTime = Val(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value)
             If (StartTime > RowStartTime) And (StartTime < RowEndTime) Or (RowStartTime > StartTime) And (RowStartTime < EndTime) Then
                msgbox "Conflict"
                ActiveCell.Select
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
             Else
                msgbox "noConflict"
             End If
         End If
      Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You never define `Target`. Is that just supposed to be `ActiveCell`?

Comment: ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 8

Comment: @Slai what can I do if I need to highlight the row instead of only a cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
```

Comment: Thank you!! In the case, I want to highlight the row but only from column C to D? should I add a range in there? @Slai

Comment: then `ActiveCell.EntireRow.Resize(, 2).Offset(, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 8` or `Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, Range("Sheet3!C:D")).Interior.ColorIndex = 8`